# CKEditor : Check if the last deleted element is "br" in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have one doubt in CKEditor.I want to Check the last deleted Element in

CKEditor is **BR** tag.How Can I check that in CKEditor

And I'm trying the below way to do this.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    allowedContent: true,
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'mode' },
        { name: 'basicstyles' }
    ],
    on: {
        contentDom: function() {     


var editor = this;

       this.editable().attachListener( editor, 'key', function( evt ) {
           // If not backspace or delete.
           if ( ( evt.data.keyCode in { 8: 1, 46: 1 } ) ) {
           // Get selected element.
           var lastElement = editor.elementPath().lastElement,
               parent = lastElement.getParent();

              console.log(lastElement,parent);

           console.log(lastElement.$); 
           document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = lastElement.$.getAttribute("src")
           }



       } );
    }
   }
} );
```

[Link For Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lkvq69f/40/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

Using the below code should do this..

```
$(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection().getRanges()[0].startContainer.$).prev()[0].tagName
```

It will give "br" as an output whenever you are deleting the BR tag in CKEDITOR.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more complex. You can delete content not only using `backspace`/`delete` keys, but also by replacing content (e.g. selecting and typing, pasting), cutting content or using different keyboard shortcuts (deleting previous/next word, deleting line, etc).
Checking what was deleted requires more complex approach.

In your case, if you would like to focus only on `br` elements, so you would like to detect if the latest modification operation removed a `br` element, I would suggest to track all `br` elements and check if all of them are present after content modification:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
  var editable = evt.editor.editable(),
      brs = editable.find( 'br' ),
      deletedBrs;

  evt.editor.on( 'change', function() {
    deletedBrs = diff( brs, editable.find( 'br' ) );
    brs = editable.find( 'br' );
  } );
} );

function diff( nodeList, newNodeList ) {
  // Check which elements were removed by diffing two nodeLists and return deleted elements.
}
```

That way you will have a list of deleted br elements after every content modification.

Comment: Ok, but it isn't giving the deleted "br" position.

Comment: And I only trigger this event when the user clicks backspace or delete button.